# Copying a folder from a Mac to an external hard drive using Terracopy: if you delete the source file does the destination file get deleted too?

Tags: mac, backup, external-disk, folders, archive

When copying a folder from a Mac to a backup external hard drive using Terracopy? If you delete the source file or folder does the destination get deleted too? This happens using Carbon Copy Cloner App.

I want to copy pictures from my Mac to an external hard drive. When I am out of space on my Mac, I want to delete some older picture folders/files on my Mac, but I still want the pictures to reside on the backup external drive. I will like the backup to be scheduled everyday.

Will Terracopy accomplish this for me or is there a better method or app?

Answer (score 1):

You're solving the wrong problem.

If you remove the source file, CCC *should* remove the destination file.  It's supposed to be a backup of the source volume.

If you want to have archival storage, then set that up.  And provide for backing it up, too.